# How to display multiple taskpanes using office.js?

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I am making an add-ins project using office.js
My product wants to support even a lower version of office.

Therefore, functions such as addins commands and application-specific API are not used. It doesn't even use the Dialog API.

I am testing the developed function on localhost.
I want to navigate to a page like <a href='../test/test.html> at localhost:3000/taskpane.html .

How do I edit Manifest.xml or js file to get the function I want?
I hope you understand that I am not good at English.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can display a menu in your test.html and  taskpane.html page like the below image. [Tab menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ycy09.png)

Comment: You're confirming that this _can_ be done, but you've offered no instruction on _how_ to do this. **As such, this fails to answer the question.** The question is, "How do I edit Manifest.xml or js file to get the function I want?"